# Container view segue to same size view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the following Storyboard:

[image]

So far, I could only achieve same size Third View Controller in the storyboard if I segue via show, but I would prefer custom method.

My goal is, to segue from Second View Controller to Third View Controller and only replace the Second View Controller which is a Container View in the (First) View Controller.

However the current output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Thank you,

Comment: Modal segue using current context mode.

Comment: @matt Same results. If I change the seque to "Modal" or "Present Modally" the Third View Controller become full size in the storyboard also.

Comment: Because you didn't use current context mode and set the first v.c. as providing the current context.

Comment: @matt Indeed, that was the problem. I set "Defines Context" in the Second View Controller, and use "Present Modally", "Current Context" segue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a modal segue with a current context mode. This example has *no code at all*: the whole thing is done by configuring the segue and the view controllers in Interface Builder:

[image]

Comment: Configuring them how? A summary of the technique (with a reference to the section of your book) would strike a nice balance between providing concrete help and plugging your book.

Comment: And does this create a stack of modal view controllers inside the container view that you then have to dismiss, or can you switch between 2 (or N) view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a segue for this. You will need to create the new view controller using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, add it as a child view controller of the parent view controller, then use the `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` method to switch `secondViewController` to `thirdViewController`.

Do a search on "Transitioning Between Child View Controllers" in the Xcode docs for more information on switching child view controllers.

### EDIT:

Matt knows more about this than I, and he says it's possible. I found a section in the Xcode docs with the heading "Transitioning Between Child View Controllers" that covers it. I've only glanced at it so far, but it explains how to do this. I suggest taking a look at that.

Comment: "I don't think you can use a segue for this" Yes, you can.

Comment: Ok, can you elaborate? I'm pretty good with Core Animation, but I don't know how to do this, and clearly the OP doesn't either. Could you write an answer explaining how to do it, or point us to a post that explains it?

Comment: My comment above explains it. My book explains it. My code examples explain it.

Comment: Your comment provides a clue. It doesn't explain it.

Comment: Okay but that doesn't make it true that you can't use a segue for this, since you can.

Comment: Sure, I was wrong, and I've learned something (which is always good.) I edited my answer to reflect that fact.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by setting the **definePresentationContext** of your red VC to Yes.
You can also use interface builder. No code required has matt says.

Check the image below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZmqU.png

Also Check Apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext

PS: excuse my english, i'm a french speaking guy